# wordpress and Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress

I am new to both Wordpress and Ruby on rails.Are these (WP and ruby on rails) two are power full tool for creating any good website .

I have seen from wordpress and ruby on rails official website that some of the popular web sites(twitter,WSJ etc.) are using these two.

Please give me are brief idea these.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really depends on what you want, what you have and how you want it. Wordpress is 'supposed' to be a blogging CMS, but its so flexible, you can even use it for web apps. (Of course you will need to write your plugins in php). If you're looking to just have a simple website and you're not too technically inclined, I'd say Wordpress is the Go-to platform. If you have some time on your hands, seriously considering web apps, Rails is a pretty advanced web-app framework which is definitely worth a go. So really, it depends.

Comment: @ Shreyas I am really interested about Rails .how can I my first step on it ?

Comment: You would have to start learning Ruby first. You can find a lot Ruby resources on the web. Once you get a decent hold on Ruby you can start working with Rails. Ruby is the language and Rails is the framework written in Ruby. Agile web development with Rails is a neat choice. Also note, you're better off starting off learning Rails 3.

Comment: @Subhransu I used this guide to get started on RoR - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html following that, you might want to try deploying a small app to heroku. Also, this tutorial/guide was pretty cool - http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book .

Answer (score 1):

Well using both seems rather impractical. They both are geared toward a different use case. Rails is for web apps whereas WP is better for normal web sites.